# Excel VBA project name disappeared after file crash

Tags: excel, vba, crash, vbe

I have an `xlsm` file that I was working on it and somehow while I was in the VBE it crashed, upon re-opening it throws this error.

[image]

I have a workbook_open event so it cannot run it of course. When I go to VBE the name of the project is gone as if the name of the project is a whitespace as you can see below

[image]

When I try to open Tools>references nothing shows up. When I click stop execution button in the VBE Excel crashes. I also tried to used a repaired and recovered `xlsb` file by Excel says the damage was too extensive that it could not recover most of the data. I don't care about the data, but I just need to recover my macros. Anyone has faced this kind of challenge? BTW the project is password protected, I can unlock it without any problem

Comment: Usually windows have a backup of old versions. Right click and press properties then old versions or something, I'm typing from my phone so.. but have a look there if you can recreate a old version.

Comment: Holding down the shift key whilst clicking on the excel icon will start excel without macros running.  This should allow you to get into the VBA IDE and check what is happening.

Comment: @freeflow I don't have a problem getting into VBE, the screenshots show it

Comment: @Andreas the previous versions show nothing, they must be gone too